# kommentarlos gelöschter Beitrag

Tags: discussion, moderation

Warum wurde [dieser (m.E. interessante) Beitrag](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/76015/36196) kommentarlos gelöscht?

Möglicherweise gibt es ein Missverständnis aufgrund eines Tippfehlers?

Im ersten Satz heißt es

> Ich kenne kein Deutsch, dieser Text wurde von Yandex-Pervers übersetzt.

Gemeint ist offenbar Yandex-**Übersetzer**, was sich anhand des russischen Originaltextes nachvollziehen lässt. Statt **переводчиком** (Übersetzer) ist dem Autor mit перево**л**чиком offenbar ein Tippfehler unterlaufen.

Der im Text dargelegte Gedanke zur Frage der Bedeutung des Namens Droßelmeier erscheint mir interessant genug, diesen Beitrag nicht als Spam zu betrachten und wenigstens nicht kommentarlos zu löschen.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe den Beitrag gelöscht, nachdem er geflagt worden war. Ich kann kein Russisch. Die deutsche Übersetzung ist (für mich) dermaßen unverständlich, dass ich darin keine Antwort erkennen konnte.

Offenbar kannst du den Beitrag besser verstehen. Wenn du ihn editierst und verbesserst, würde ich die Löschung rückgängig machen.

Comment: Verstehe ich alles. Für den immerhin möglichen Fall, dass sich da jemand die Mühe gemacht hat, einen Beitrag zu schreiben, der dann leider *lost in translation* ist, finde ich es nur einfach sehr unhöflich, **kommentarlos** zu löschen. Nein, ich kann das leider auch nicht verbessern und Googles Translator scheint mir noch schlechter abzuschneiden als der von OP gewählte.

Comment: Möglicherweise gibt es hier jemanden, der gut Russisch spricht und editieren könnte.

Comment: @Olafant Ja, du hast Recht. Ich habe jetzt noch einen Kommentar geschrieben, um die Situation zu erklären. Das hätte ich gleich beim Löschen machen sollen. Ich hab den Beitrag nicht so ernst genommen, wie er es verdient gehabt hätte. Danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: Vielen Dank! So finde ich das akzeptabel und hoffe darauf, dass sich hier jemand findet, der Russisch spricht und im günstigsten Fall Hoffmanns und Nurejews Interpretation des Stoffs kennt.

Comment: Ich sehe gerade in einem Kommentar unter der Frage, dass die Muttersprache des Fragenstellers Russisch ist. Der kann mit einer Reputation von 201 aber höchstwahrscheinlich die gelöschte Antwort nicht sehen.

Comment: @Olafant Ja, das mag sein. Die Sprache des Forums ist aber Deutsch oder Englisch.

Comment: Ja, das mag sein. Der Fragensteller könnte die Antwort, die in Deutsch und Russisch vorliegt, sowohl verstehen als auch editieren.